# Why yoga discourages cold water bath in the morning but many hindus do it as a part of their devotion/purification?

Tags: yoga

Texts like Gherenda Samhita discourage activities like fasting, taking bath in the morning, long travel(pilgrimage) etc which are in opposition with what other worships recommend. Why is that?

Comment: Well, in order to take a closer look to answer this question it would be advisable first to see the context in which this particular activity is discouraged there in the scripture. However if that does not help, then all we can say is that the various Hindu Dharma scriptures sometimes give different answers (instructions) to specific application or simply different answers for different groups of people. These answers can sometimes seem to be so different that they are even contradictory. By the way, are you sure that the scripture is named exactly "Gher***e***nda"?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa It's actually called the Gheranda Samhita, and it's a modern text on Hatha Yoga: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gheranda_Samhita

Comment: Yes it is called Gheranda Samhita. In fifth chapter, sloka 31 it says: प्रातःस्नानोपवासादि कायक्लेशविधिम्  तथा ।
एकाहारं निराहारं यामान्ते च न कारयेत् ॥३१॥ He should avoid early (morning before sunrise) baths, fasting etc or anything giving pain to the body; so also is prohibited to him eating only once a day, or not eating at all. But he may remain without food for 3 hours.